# Flutter 2.5.0, casting parent to child class fails (ok in 1.22.6)

Tags: flutter, dart, inheritance, casting

I am migrating from Flutter 1.22.6 to 2.5.0 (dart 2.14) and have a question on explicit casting.

In my code I have a plugin API that returns a base class object:

```
Future<BaseData> getReport(String type) async {
  return BaseData.fromJson(json.decode(report))
}
```

The BaseData.fromJson can build a number of different child object, like this:

```
static BaseData fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
  switch (json['type'] as String) {
    case 'typeOne':
      return ChildDataOne.fromJson(json);
    case 'typeTwo':
      return ChildDataTwo.fromJson(json);
   etc
```

Then I call the plugin function like this:

```
ChildDataOne childDataTypeOne = await dataManager.getReport(String type)
```

and in Flutter 1.22.6 this works fine. A ChildDataOne object is returned because the BaseData.fromJson constructor always builds the correct child type and no explicit casting is needed.

However, in Flutter 2.5.0 I get:

```
A value of type 'BaseData' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'ChildDataOne'.
```

I can of course cast it such as:

```
final childDataTypeOne = await dataManager.getReport() as ChildDataOne;
```

but I am unclear on why this is needed in Flutter 2.5.0 when it was not required in 1.22.6 or if I am doing something the wrong way.

All comments are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not the Flutter or Dart version which makes the difference but the minimum Dart version in the `pubspec.yaml` file.

With the minimum Dart version at 2.11.0 your code works, also with Dart 2.14.0.

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.11.0 <3.0.0"
```

Once you change to the minium version 2.12.0 your code fails to compile.

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"
```

If you use the minimum version 2.12.0, "non-nullable by default" gets automatically activated.

The error which you get is using the [templateInvalidAssignmentError](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/268290725dcc604c17ca918a9b97d160ce74a953/pkg/front_end/lib/src/fasta/fasta_codes_cfe_generated.dart#L2117). This error is raised by the method [`ensureAssignable`](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/78266c3464e1216c804994cbac18a52663ed7a6c/pkg/front_end/lib/src/fasta/type_inference/type_inferrer.dart#L496) in `type_inferrer.dart`. Within that method there are multiple uses of the `isNonNullableByDefault` property. One of them invalidates your code.

Comment: Thanks @Janux for the detailed explaination. Then I assume explicit casting is now needed. The only thing I did not fully understand from your answer was "also with Dart 2.14.0". It kinda sounded that it should work again in dart 2.14.0 but I tried and it fails so I assume you meant explicit casting will always be required in 2.12+.

Comment: I mean, I have used Dart 2.14.0 to run a minimal version of your program and it passed, as long as the minimum Dart version in the pubspec YAML is declared as something below 2.12.0.

Comment: Then I follow, thanks a lot.